# Keeping textures on a blender file when exporting to Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, textures, blender

I have a Blender model and it has a lot of objects with a lot of different textures so assigning all the textures in Unity would be a long process, (and I'm not even sure how to assign textures in Unity). All my textures are gone when I put the model in Unity. Is there any way to keep the textures when you put the model into Unity?

Comment: Please make your question a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example [mcve]. Also check [ask] to make your post answerable.

Comment: As a matter of fact you need to manually place textures since blender and unity use different shader systems. Adding to Prateek coment stackoverflow is for code only, so next time you have a question not directly related to code try using the game development stack exchange.

Comment: Sorry, thought stack overflow  was for all game design questions. I can't use stack exchange since I can't sign in to my account whenever I push sign in it just sends me back to the homepage still not signed in. Thanks for the answer.